# Fixed header + Fixed Right-Side Navigation + Fluid Content Area

Tags: css, layout, fixed

I'd like to create a Layout where the header and Right side navigation are fixed and the
content area is fluid.

I attached a screen shot to help explain this better.

If this is possible, I would really appreciate some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;};

.wrap {width: 980px; margin: auto;}
header {width: 100%; height: 200px; float: left;}
#content {width: 100%; padding: 0 0 0 150px; min-height: 500px;}
aside {width: 150px; min-height: 100%; height: auto; float: left; margin-left: 150px;}

<div class="wrap">
<header>
</header>
<div id="content">
<aside>
</aside>
</div>
</div>
```

This will get you what you want. This is for HTML5 although just change (header and aside) to div tags.